# Load markdown file into html page to display accessible content

Tags: javascript, html, markdown

I have a question:
How to Load markdown file into html page to display accessible content in the runtime?

I need to load different md content in different html pages using vanilla JavaScript.

I have limitation running local webserver or install nodejs at my work computer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)